# Try & Catch in double Array not working as I expected

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch, numberformatexception

I'm trying to perform a try catch on a user input and place the user input into an array if it passes the check but if I enter an invalid input, it would replace that index with 0 and move onto the next index. I'm trying to figure out how to get a reprompt to work inside the for loop so that the invalid value in that particular index gets replaced with a valid user input. The order of the values in the array doesn't matter. I'm trying to do this without importing other Java libraries!

I would very much appreciate any help ! I'm new to programming and Java. Thank you for your time !

```
public static double[] getAmount()
   {
      int MAX_NUM = 10;
      double[] numArray = new double[MAX_NUM];
      for (int i = 0; i < numArray.length;i++)
      {
         double numInput;
         do
         {
            try
            {
               numInput = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter amounts in $: "));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
               numInput = MAX_NUM - 11;
            }
            if (numInput < 0 || numInput > 999999)
            {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error. Please enter valid amount in dollars");
               numInput = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter amount in $: "));
            }
            else
            {
               numArray[i] = numInput;
            }
          }
          while (numInput < 0 && numInput > 999999);
       }
       return numArray;      
    }
```

Comment: you should try while loop since you need control over the i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static double[] getAmount()
{
  int MAX_NUM = 10;
  double[] numArray = new double[MAX_NUM];
  int i = 0;
  while (i < numArray.length)
  {
     double numInput;

        try
        {
           numInput = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter amounts in $: "));
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
           numInput = MAX_NUM - 11;
        }
        if (numInput < 0 || numInput > 999999)
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error. Please enter valid amount in dollars");
           numInput = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter amount in $: "));
        }
        else
        {
           numArray[i] = numInput;
           i++;
        }
   }

   return numArray;
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much ! I was so stuck on the idea of using a for loop. I ended up removing the statement after the error message in the if statement and it worked perfectly. Thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public static double[] getAmount()
   {
      int MAX_NUM = 10;
      double[] numArray = new double[MAX_NUM];
      for (int i = 0; i < numArray.length;i++)
      {
         double numInput;
         do
         {
            try
            {
               numInput = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter amounts in $: "));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
               numInput = MAX_NUM - 11;
            }
            if (numInput < 0 || numInput > 999999)
            {

               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error. Please enter valid amount in dollars");
            }
          }
          while (numInput < 0 || numInput > 999999);
          numArray[i] = numInput;
       }
       return numArray;      
    }
```